# Civicrm local db error

Tags: error, database

**My Specs**

I migrated a production Drupal 7/Civicrm 7.x-4.7.9 site to my local machine. 
For my stack, I  am running MAMP and PHP 5.6.32, the production server is on PHP 5.6.33

I downloaded all files, and databases (there are two, one for Civicrm and one for Drupal 7).

Took a while, but got it set up and running and changed all urls in the DB. no issues so far.

but now when I got to ...site\civicrm (yes for some reason the local is running on two back slashes in stead of one -- if this is an issue, otherwise it's secondary to the below unless related...)

**And here is what I need help with:**

I get this error:

Sorry but we are not able to provide this at the moment.
'civicrm/showevents': 
Could not find access_callback in path tree, 
Could not find page_arguments in path tree, 
Could not find is_ssl in path tree

---

Things I've done so far: Cleared all cache

Any thoughts?

**Thanks in Advance!!!**

Comment: Make sure you have correct path values set in `Administer -> System Settings -> Resource URLs` and `Administer -> System Settings -> Directories`

Comment: If you click on the Question mark on the "directory" page make sure that the path it shows corresponds to your local file system as well. If it doesn't you might need to edit your civicrm.settings.php file.

Comment: I agree with @jitendra-fuzion and also check $civicrm_root variable and variable for templates_c directory in civicrm_settings.php file. Also Check if your DB credentials are correct according to localhost

Comment: @jitendra-fuzion, the administer section would this be found in the civicrm settings in the back end?  if so, I can't actually get to the admin page of civi -- I get the same error : Sorry but we are not able to provide this at the moment.
'civicrm/showevents': Could not find access_callback in path tree, Could not find page_arguments in path tree, Could not find is_ssl in path tree

Comment: @HassanFarooq and luke Stewart, I checked both civi  and db credentials... everything is populating right and now the double slash is gone (there was a trailing slash in settings.php). I've been playing with different things that could be the $civicrm_root and the c directoy, no luck yet though...

Answer (score 1):

The path `civicrm/showevents` does not seem to be a part of core. I think you have an extension enabled on your site which is creating a problem.

- Disable or uninstall `Event Calendar(com.osseed.eventcalendar)` from Extension page `civicrm/admin/extensions?reset=1`.
- If you can't access the extension page, try disabling this using `cv` command OR directly modifying `civicrm_extension` table in your database. Set `is_active` value to `0`.

  ```
  $ cv ext:disable com.osseed.eventcalendar
  ```
- Clear cache OR rebuild the menu using `civicrm/menu/rebuild?reset=1`.

Comment: I think you nailed it -- the  Event Calendar is an extention. I followed your advice and went into the database (via PhpMyAdmin) and set the civicrm_extension tables is_active to zero. 

but now now I am getting a " The page isn’t redirecting properly"  Error with " his problem can sometimes be caused by disabling or refusing to accept cookies." --looking into this now

Comment: and I am also getting this error... in dblogs for drupal, I think they might be related...

Warning: opendir(http://localhost:8888/drupal/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Campaign/xml/Menu/): failed to open dir: not implemented in CRM_Utils_File::getFilesByExtension() (line 438 of /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/drupal/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Utils/File.php).